# Sonoff Switch eWeLink versus Tasmodo

Tags: esp8266

I vaguely recall reading that if I setup my Sonoff 4channel switch on eWeLink, I can't ever then upgrade it to Tasmoto. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to flash Tasomota successfully.